# Why do I multiply two matrices together to find their Rigid Body Transform Using SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

Given two $N\times M$ matrices $A,B$ where I wish to find the best mapping of $A\to B$ using rotation and translation I can use Least-Squares SVD to find the rotation and translation matrices. Via:

> $H= A^T * B$
>
> $SVD(H)\to U,S,V^T$
>
> Rotation $=V*U^T$
>
> Translation $=B-R*A^T$

What does the matrix $H$ represent? If $A=B$ then Matrix $H$ should be the identity matrix, so is $H$ really just some kind of difference matrix then? Can anyone elaborate further?

Comment: Thanks for Formatting Help!

Comment: $A^T B$ is a measure of similarity for orthonormal matrices. So if $A$ and $B$ are equal then you get the identity. So that would work for rotations only.

Comment: I don't grasp it entirely yet, but I think $XWY^T$ [here](https://igl.ethz.ch/projects/ARAP/svd_rot.pdf) has to do with that. (Eq 16 to 21) And $X=A$ and $Y=B$, and $W$ is a diagonal matrix of weights that later turn out to be irrelevant